# Why are my images taking so long to load when I use getimagesize

Tags: php, image, performance

I am really struggling to grasp why this is dragging our load times down but when I have the image size check in, it takes 5 seconds to load every image but wen I take it out it takes 0.0000005 seconds to load.
This is the code that seams to slow it down:

```
$imageSize = @getimagesize($image['Link']);
if($imageSize !== false){
    list($width, $height) = $imageSize;
    //Check if image is square
    if(abs(1 - ($width / $height)) > 0.02){
        $resize = true;
    }
} else {
    $image['Link'] = "assets/img/no_image_available.svg";
}
```

Or if there is a better way to check if an image is close to being square, that would be much appreciated

Comment: 5 seconds doe seem excessive, Is this content hosted externally? how long does it take your web browser to download that link?

Comment: 5 Seconds almost sounds like a DNS time out, is your server able to wget the url faster than 5 seconds?

Comment: Is `$image['Link']` a file system path - or a URL ...?

Comment: It's a URL, the images are in an s3 bucket and load super quick when following the link. I read that the getimagesize function can be quite terrible to use though in terms of load times so I started running the checks in the js after load to try and imp through the issue